# Error message not displaying on Form validation

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I am creating a simple form with validation with html razor and javascript. One validation that I have is to check for empty fields.

**Expected Result:**
Error message to be displayed (below the input field) if the user clicks the Submit button without entering any value in the input field.

**Actual Result:**
No error message displayed even if the user clicks the Submit button without entering any value in the input field. It seems like the html file is not communicating with the JS file at all. I tried various ways such as clearing browser cache and checking for typos, but to no avail.

**Here are the relevant codes:**

**form.cshtml**

```
@* Display error message *@
<div id="error"></div>

<form id ="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="deviceId">Device ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deviceId" placeholder="Enter Device Device ID">
    </div>
    
    @* Energy Usage *@
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="energyUsage">Energy Usage</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="energyUsage" placeholder="Enter Energy Usage">
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="performValidation()" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="js/validation.js"></script>
}
```

**validation.js**

```
const deviceId = document.getElementById('deviceId')
const energyUsage = document.getElementById('energyUsage')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')

function performValidation()
{
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

        // list to store the error messages
        let messages = []

        // if device ID field is an empty string or user did not pass in any device Id
        if (deviceId.value === ' ' || deviceId.value == null) {
            // send the error message
            messages.push('Device ID is required')
            // console.log('No Device ID retrieved')
        }

        // if there is error, prevent the form from submitting
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault()

            // check errorElement
            errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ') // to separate error elements from each other
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Try checking for an empty string for the input value: `deviceId.value === ''`. You actually check for a single space or `null` (which never will happen).

Comment: The [Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space when checking for empty string:

validation.js

```
if (deviceId.value === '' || deviceId.value == null)
```

to route the html file to js file correctly:

form.cshtml

```
<script src="~/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get an idea.

```js
<script>
form_validation();

function form_validation() {
  const formName = document.getElementsByName('form-name')[0];
  const fieldsArray = Array.from(formName.elements);

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('form-validation-error');
  formName.insertBefore(span, formName.children[0]);

  function validate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < fieldsArray.length; i++) {

      if (fieldsArray[i].value == "") {
        //console.log(fieldsArray[i]);
        const str = fieldsArray[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
        span.innerHTML = `${str} can not be empty!`;
        span.style.display = 'block';
        span.style.margin = '10px 0';
        fieldsArray[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
        return false;
        break;
      } else {
        fieldsArray[i].style.border = '1px solid black';
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  formName.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate()) {
      
      //formName.submit(); //uncomment this line to submit the form
      console.log('Validation pass. You can submit the form!');
    } else {
      console.log('Field is empty. Validation not pass!');
    }
  });
} 
</script>
```

```css
input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.form-validation-error {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" name="form-name">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input name="fname" value="">
  <br/>
  <label for="fname">Last Name</label>
  <input name="lname" value="">
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
  </form
```